# Update DataGrid on updating a property from the class which is an item for an ObservableCollection binded to the DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I've a problem on updating a datagrid cells when properies are changed.

So I have such program structure:

there is an ObservableCollection which contains some objects. These objects as you understand contain some properties.

The program is always looking for new objects. If one found than it is being added to the Repository using NHibernate. But the ObservableCollection does't get changed. By the way this collection is from the base class. You should know it, because code is borrowed from Microsoft example of WPF and MVVM. The collection is AllObjects.

I do understand that to update the cells I need to work with properties of the ViewModel but how could I get to AllObjects if it is in a base class.

Well, I hope somebody will understand what I wrote here... Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Well everything was pretty easy... as usual. I made an event on updating a repository. And when the rep was updated I decided to go throgh AllObjects find an object and set a new value to it.